# How to define functions with arguments in Tcl to allocate them a value from another Tcl script?

Tags: function, tcl, vivado, memory-mapping

I am using Tcl scripts in Xilinx Vivado FPGA Design tool (ver 2017.3). In my design, I have manually set the memory addresses in a Tcl file entitled memory_map.tcl as shown below:

**memory_mapp.tcl**

```
set_property offset 0x40000000 [get_bd_addr_segs {ublazePCIe_hier/microblaze_0/Data/SEG_dlmb_bram_if_cntlr_Mem}]
```

I want to define the address 0x40000000 as a parameter to be able to allocate a value to that from another Tcl file. In another Tcl file entitled **main.tcl**, I would like to call a function including that parameter, then give it a value. So, I have done the following trial:

in my memory_map.tcl file :

```
    proc memory_mapping {addr1} {
            set_property offset **addr1** [get_bd_addr_segs {ublazePCIe_hier/microblaze_0/Data/SEG_dlmb_bram_if_cntlr_Mem}]
}
```

then, in my main.tcl file, I have written:

```
source memory_mapping.tcl
set addr1 0x40000000
memory_mapping{*}$value
foreach {*} $value {
       memory_mapping $addr1
       break
}

puts "Address is : $addr1"
```

I am not really sure what I have done is correct or not because the script does not work properly. Kind helps and hints are in advance appreciated!

Bests,
M

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have so many `*` characters in there.

Once inside the procedure, `addr` is a variable like any other, so:

```
 set_property offset $addr1 [get_bd_addr_segs {ublazePCIe_hier/microblaze_0/Data/SEG_dlmb_bram_if_cntlr_Mem}]
```

And to call the procedure, you simply pass the variable's value.

```
  memory_mapping $value
```

You don't need that `foreach` loop, as you already have a call to memory_mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to try to understand what your code does / should do.
Therefore I'm making some assumtions - maybe they're wrong ...

You have a procedure `memory_mapping` and you want to pass an address as argument `addr1` to it.
Then your `set_property` call should look like Brad Lanam already showed:

```
proc memory_mapping {addr1} {
    set_property offset $addr1 [get_bd_addr_segs {ublazePCIe_hier/microblaze_0/Data/SEG_dlmb_bram_if_cntlr_Mem}]
}
```

Your `main.tcl` needs to pass the address to the `memory_mapping` procedure and should therefore look like:

```
source memory_mapping.tcl
set addr1 0x40000000
memory_mapping $addr1
```

Now I'm  guessing why you wanted to use a `foreach` loop: You could do that if you want to set several addresses - but the syntax [(see Tcl documentation)](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm) must be:

```
source memory_mapping.tcl
set addrList {0x40000000 0x40000001 0x40000002}   ;# set 3 addresses
foreach addr $addrList {
    puts $addr   ;# some progress/info on the Tcl console (stdout)
    memory_mapping $addr
}
```